# Getting 'connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000' error while sending POST request by axios

Tags: node.js, axios

I want to send a POST request to the server at the route ''localhost: 3000/api/v1/user" using axios but I get an error  "connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000".Please help me. Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

axios
  .post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/user",
    {
      firstName: "Fred",
      lastName: "Flintstone",
    },
    { headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" } }
  )
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data || "hello");
    res.send(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });

app.route("/api/v1/user").get((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1", () =>
  console.log("Server is listening at port 3000")
);
```

Comment: If this worked wouldn't it result in an infinite loop?

Comment: Yes you are right thanks. I have edited the post can you tell why this does not work

Comment: Your `axios.post` code is running when the file loads before the app.listen code. Are you sure this is what you want to do? I would expect your `axios.post` to be in a client-side script somewhere that the browser loads via some HTML. If you do that and access that HTML page after your run the script that you have the `app.listen` (this needs to keep running) it should work

Comment: Thanks,yes it worked by including axios.post in the client side javascript. Does this mean that all axios methods need to be used in the client side except possibly GET (because GET worked in that backend script

Comment: You need to separate what is meant to happen on the remote user's browser and what is meant to happen on your server. For example authentication typically is the remote user sends their credentials to the server and the server responds with a success (possible a token or cookie as well) or failiure. You can't authenticate the user only on the client side because that means exposing user credentials to the world. You can't authenticate only on the server side because who are you actually authenticating? You need to consider this for all potential requests you want to create and handle.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will learn to think like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems

## Time

Your HTTP request is made from the same program as the one which runs the server which listens for the HTTP request.

Aside from this appearing to be rather pointless, you are making the request **before** you call `listen` so are doing so before the server exists to make the request to.

Timing is important. You could move the call to `axios.post` to the end of the program, but I don’t understand why you would want them in the same program in the first place.

## Network interfaces

> ```
> app.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1",
> ```

You are listening on port 3000 of the 127.0.0.1 network interface (which is the standard IPv4 loopback interface).

> ```
> connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
> ```

Your request to `localhost:3000` is being resolved to port 3000 of the `::1` network interface (which is the standard IPv6 loopback interface).

That isn’t where your server is listening, so the computer refuses to let you connect.

Either:

- Change the network interface you are listening on in the by changing the second argument of the call to `listen` (or remove it to listen on all network interfaces) *or*
- Change your hosts file to resolve localhost on ipV4